# How can I get a key value from an array that has object inside

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Imagine I have something like this:

```
const myArray = [
    {
        Email:example@example.com,
        Password:1234,
        Username:myname
    }
]
```

How can I access email value inside of object in easier way? I know can do some looping or mapping then using `for of` or something like that but is there any better way?

I want to do a check like that:

```
const otherArray = [
    {
        Email:example@notexample.com,
        Username:myname,
        Password:1234
    }
]
```

If the `Email` value inside of `myArray` is equals to the value of `otherArray` then if it does:

- `return true`

Comment: `otherArray[0].Email == myArray[0],Email` would be a direct compare given your simple example but this feels like some information may be missing in your question perhaps?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more info? If you're comparing a value between two arrays, there must be unique identifier to link them. For example, `Email` or `Username`.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss it will return undefined (I tested before). there is an object inside of array. you can't just simply do that.

Comment: @RoMilton it is a login/signUP form made by react. I want to control my input to not have redundant values. I use UUID package to generate unique identifier

Comment: Looks like you just need make a difference between two arrays

Comment: @muller I noticed I have a syntax in my comment but the comment stands as when you do `otherArray[0].Email == myArray[0].Email` the `[0]` indicates which object instance in the array by using the 0 index (first one as arrays are 0 based).  Now if by chance your array includes more than one, then that would only reference that first one (assumes it does exist) and if there are more, then that is a different question - and you probably need to update your question with more objects in the array in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method.

**Working Demo :**

```js
const myArray = [
    {
        Email: 'example@example.com',
        Username: 'myname',
        Password: 1234
    }, {
        Email: 'example1@example.com',
        Username: 'myname1',
        Password: 5678
    }, {
        Email: 'example2@example.com',
        Username: 'myname2',
        Password: 8756
    }
];

const otherArray = [
    {
        Email: 'example@notexample.com',
        Password: 1234,
        Username: 'myname'
    }
];

const res = myArray.some(obj => obj.Email === otherArray[0].Email);

console.log(res); // false as example@example.com is not equal to example@notexample.com.
```

Answer (score 0):

Some examples (with the syntax error fixed on the values)

```js
let myname = "I create sntax errors";
const myArray = [{
  Email: "example@example.com",
  Password: "1234",
  Username: myname
}];

const otherArray = [{
  Email: "example@notexample.com",
  Username: myname,
  Password: "1234"
}];

const otherArrayAlso = [{
  Email: "example@example.com",
  Username: myname,
  Password: "1234"
}];
let isMatch = myArray[0].Email == otherArray[0].Email;
console.log(myArray[0].Email, otherArray[0].Email);
console.log("IsMatch:", isMatch);
console.log(myArray[0].Email == otherArrayAlso[0].Email);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check like this

```js
const myArray = [
  {
    Email: 'test@test.com',
    Age: 30,
  },
  {
    Email: 'One@test.com',
    Age: 24,
  },
  {
    Email: 'Two@test.com',
    Age: 20,
  },
]

const otherArray = [
  {
    Email: 'Three@test.com',
    Age: 30,
  },
  {
    Email: 'test@test.com',
    Age: 24,
  },
  {
    Email: 'Four@test.com',
    Age: 20,
  },
]

let found = false;

const otherArrayEmails = otherArray.map(item => item.Email);
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
   if (otherArrayEmails.includes(myArray[i].Email)) {
      found = true;
      break;
   }
} 
console.log(found)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the email with `myArray[0].Email`. But first change your array to

```
const myArray = [
    {
        'Email': 'example@example.com',
        'Password': 1234,
        'Username': 'myname'
    }
]
```